# Terraform: eks_manage_node_group issue

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I am a new hire and tasked with a project to specify the disk_size using the modules from:
https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/master/examples/eks_managed_node_group/

We used to be able to specify the disk_size:

```
`eks_managed_node_group_defaults = {
disk_size = 50
}`
```

Now with the recent update we can only specify the disk_size if we set the use_custom_launch_template = false which uses the eks_manged_node_group_default template:

```
`eks_managed_node_group_defaults = {
use_custom_launch_template = false
disk_size = 50
}`
```

the problem with this is that we lose the benefits of the, resource "aws_eks_cluster" "this"

from:https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/master/main.tf

specifically I lose the following:

```
metadata_options {
http_endpoint               = "enabled" -> null
http_put_response_hop_limit = 2 -> null
http_tokens                 = "required" -> null
}
monitoring {
enabled = true -> null
}
```

is there any way I can enable the monitoring and metadata_options while using the EKS managed node group default launch template?

The solution was to use the use_custom_launch_template = false, but with a trade off of losing medata_options and monitoring, which i want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

solved. used the terraform block below:

```
block_device_mappings = {
  xvda = {
    device_name = "/dev/xvda"
    ebs         = {
      volume_size           = 50
      volume_type           = "gp3"
      iops                  = 3000
      throughput            = 125
      encrypted             = true
      delete_on_termination = true
}
```